# Neo4j create node

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using repository which extends `GraphRepository`. It is easy to do some queries or save nodes by derived methods, but is there any simply way to create node? For example, for queries I can use `repository.findAll()`, to save it is `repository.save()` but why there is no method like `repository.createNode()`? If something like that doesn't exist, what is the easiest way to create node?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Hi, but it's a simple question - I just ask if some of that method exists and, if not, what is the best way to solve this - I don't ask about full solution, just a way to do it and that is not any homework. What have I done already is that I found only solution with db factory, but I trust there is an easier way, like in case of queries or saving.

Answer (score -1):

A node is defined in Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) with the annotation `@NodeEntity` at the class level on a domain object (POJO).  A usual pattern then is for any domain objects that require persistence support you would create a `Neo4jRepository` or `GraphRepository` for them.  This way when you call `repository.save(nodeEntity)` you are actually saving the node itself.  Having another method like `createNode()` is therefore redundant.

Remember, `save()` handles both creation and updating of nodes.